# How to check a user's current userpoints balance with Rules?

Tags: rules, userpoints

I am interested in creating a rule that checks a user's userpoints and then the rule performs an action.

Currently the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module doesn't have such condition. I read that this is possible to do with a Rules Component, that is used as a Rules Condition.

Could someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution:
I created a rule set,where I add two rules:
1)Load the user points
2)Data comparison of user points

After creation of the Rule set,I created the main rule where I added as an action the Rule Set.Done!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there is no Rules *Condition* to ***check a user's current userpoints balance***.

Have a look at this Rules example (in Rules export format):

```
{ "rules_display_userpoints_after_updating_content" : {
    "LABEL" : "Display userpoints after updating content",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "userpoints_rules", "rules", "rules_conditional" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_rules_get_current_points" : {
          "USING" : { "user" : [ "site:current-user" ], "tid" : "all" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "loaded_points" : { "total_points" : "Number of points in all categories together" } }
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "You now have [total-points:value] points" } },
      { "CONDITIONAL" : [
          {
            "IF" : { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "total-points" ], "op" : "\u003C", "value" : "20" } },
            "DO" : [
              { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "You have sufficient points (you still have [total-points:value] ...)." } }
            ]
          },
          { "ELSE" : [
              { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "You DO NOT have sufficient points (you only have [total-points:value] ...)." } }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It does retrieve, as the very first Rules Action (not Rules Condition!) the current amount of user points of a user. If the amount is at least 20, it will display a message starting with "You have sufficient points ...", otherwise the message starts with "You DO NOT have sufficient points ...".

In this example I'm using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, though you could also rework the Rules Action to performing Rules Components (in which you add the appropriate Rules Conditions), so that you don't need this extra module.

So the clue to make this rule work is the very first Rules Action "***Load user points of a user***".